# Deep learning Image model which takes into account the previous output

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Which model should I use if the Input to the Deep neural net is an Image; but the output is single value depending not only on the input image but also on the previous output(prediction) of the net?

Answer (score 1):

Question is too broad, but in general it is [Recurrent Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network).

There are various architectures for RNNs themselves though. For example, [Long-Short Term Memory](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) is one of the famous ones.

On the other hand, from your task description it seems like you need CRNN (convolutional recurrent neural network). There are several implementations of such architecture, for example [this one](https://github.com/bgshih/crnn)

Also a very good list of various RNN architectures and their implementations could be found [here](https://github.com/kjw0612/awesome-rnn).